# Filter by attribute is slow for customer collection using addAttributeToFilter() function

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, performance, eav-attributes, mysql-indexes

I have created a custom attribute called username for Customer which is searchable in admin grid. But whenever I search by username for SSO it takes much time (2-3 sec). Below are the code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
        $collection = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('username', $username)
                    ->load();
```

Below is the query from sql log:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_username`.`value` AS `username` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_username` ON (`at_username`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_username`.`attribute_id` = '181') WHERE (at_username.value = 'vaibhav')
```

Comment: Hi Vaibhav, what is SSO single-sign on? And are you using same code for SSO that load the whole collection?

Comment: Yes its Single-sign on and I am using above code to find entity_id of customer by username.

Answer (score 0):

To get `entity_id` of the customer by customer attribute (your case is `username`), you can use `ResourceConnection` which will speed up your performance:

In your `__construct()` method, inject `ResourceConnection`:

```
protected $connection;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    .....
) {
    $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
}
```

Then in your method:

```
$select = $this->connection->select()->from('customer_entity_varchar', 'entity_id')->where('value= ?', (string)$username);
$result = $connection->fetchOne($select);
$customerId = (false === $result) ? null : (int)$result;
```

Comment: Still it has same performance. Will adding another key: (attribute_id, value) help?

Comment: I think my way will get best performance for your case. As you can see, this code use runs direct Sql query to select data from `customer_entity_varchar` table without using JOIN between tables.

Comment: Yes but there is no direct index for field value. I think I should add index and then use direct SQL without joins. Will try and post here.